# pyspark - spark - how to create a parallel multistage task using RDD

Tags: python, algorithm, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using python and would like to create a job that is as follows: 
1.the job has n parts that can happen in parallel. 
2.each part has m sub parts that need to be sequential

I would like spark to manage the fault tolerance for me therefor I tried to use RDD, the issue is that I don't find a way to create that "two dimensional" RDD, only flat ones.

Is there any way to do so with spark and pyspark?

I need it to deal with faults, and to be parallel.

Maybe some way of using a regular RDD and force some jobs to happen before the others? maybe something that is more like wait for?

I guess i can create n threads each running a RDD of it's own but that seems a bit blunt...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways i familiar with to add multithreading to your job.

1.
Lets say you have a RDD with X partitions and every partition has ~Y elements.
your RDD is RDD[A] and you want to transform it to RDD[B], but the convert A->B is a little heavy and take time.
Instead use the regular RDD[A].map(A=>transform(A)) that iterate every row in partition sequencley, you can use mapPartition that give you List[A](the elements in every partition) and you can create a multithreaded transform on the list, that can save time.
*NOTE: mapPartitions give you an iterator, so collect it to List will bring all the elements to memory, be careful.

2.
Lets say you done with your ETL, you have RDD[A] that you cached and now you want to write it to 3 diffrent datesources (I hope you`ll use kafka instead but lets say that is the scenario).

instead of doing:

```
RDD[A].saveToDataSource1
RDD[A].saveToDataSource2
RDD[A].saveToDataSource3
```

and make it sequencly you can use multithreading over here and do it parallel.
The same you can do if you read from 3 different datasources and than union them for example.

That is two cases i see when multithreading can help you in spark, all other options, spark is taking care of them already to be parallel as much as he can.

Comment: Can you provide a working code example? This seems promising